# MacOS Donet Error When Use Sonarqube "The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5" were not found"

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine, sonarqube

I've searched the same Error before this,but the answers are almost about windows. Not correspond to my question.

So here is my question,I've installed the .Net Core 2.1.402 
[image: DonetCoreVersionScreenShot]

And Mono 5.18.0.240
[image: MonoScreenShot]

Because I want to analyse the Unity's C# project with SonarQube.
So When I Enter the target file with command line and do "donet build Assembly-CSharp.csproj"

An Error happens.

[image: ErrorScreenShot]

I've searched the solution of this on mac, the answer is always to install mono, but I've already installed mono and nothing changed.

Comment: Most Unity projects should target .NET Framework 4.x today as 3.5 profile is obsolete. Besides, you should use Mono’s MSBuild to compile the project, not `dotnet build`.

Comment: Hi Lex Li ,Thanks for reply,your solution are really solve my problem!                
I've solved the problem by msbuild <myproject>.sln command line.                  
 And about Unity projects,because my project is an older one that depends on .Net framework 3.5.So that's the reason why the issues occured . Anyway,the problem was solved,Thank you again~.